# NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type - Objective-C With Swift Library (Charts)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, ios-charts

I'm using the iOS charts library, and I'm encountering the following error message:

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

I'm trying to implement a line graph with the following Objective-C code:

```
NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
set1 = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals];
[dataSets addObject:set1];
LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithDataSets:dataSets];
_chartView.data = data;
```

The error is occuring on this line within the **ChartViewBase.swift** file.

```
for set in _data!.dataSets
```

`_data` is a `ChartData` object and `dataSets` is a `[IChartDataSet]` Swift Array.

What is a workaround for working with Swift arrays in Objective-C?

Comment: How are you setting up the yVals array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follow.

```
    NSMutableArray *xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0;i<dataPoints.count;i++)
    {
        [xVals addObject:[dataPoints objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *yVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];        
    for (int i=0;i<values.count;i++)
    {
        int val = [([values objectAtIndex:i])intValue];
        [yVals addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:(int)val xIndex:i]];
    }

    LineChartDataSet *set1 = nil;
    set1 = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals label:@""];

    NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [dataSets addObject:set1];
    LineChartData *data = [[LineChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSets:dataSets];
    lineChart.data = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just giving an answer it would probably be better to understand what is happening and THEN proceed to a possible solution. I had the same issue and for me I was not wrapping my values around the `ChartDataEntry` class.

E.G.

This one threw the error for me

```
NSArray *data = <some data>
LineChartDataSet *dataSet = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:data label:@"Predictions"];
```

Vs.

This one worked fine!

```
NSArray *data = <some data>
NSMutableArray<ChartDataEntry *> *entries = [NSMutableArray new];

NSInteger index = 0;
for (NSNumber *value in data) {
    [entries addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:index y:[value doubleValue]]];
    index++;
}

LineChartDataSet *dataSet = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:entries label:@"Predictions"];
```